# How to add background color to a multi-line paragraph in CSS?

Tags: html, css

## So this is the concept:

[image]

Here's the basic sample [I made this on codepen](https://codepen.io/billcastillo/pen/WJNzrE) but there's a lack of padding for each end of a line.

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 1em;
  max-width: 500px;
}

p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  
  /* Main Style for the paragraph effect */
  display: inline;
  background: #191c34;
  padding: 4px;
  line-height: 1.8;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>
    The latest console of the world renown nintendo company which produced some of the most loved games of your childhood and the children today.
  </p>
</div>
```

I remember there was a solution using text-shadows / box-shadows?

Comment: what's the problem, it looks good to me?

Comment: Just set larger padding for `<p>` tag. eg. `padding: 7px;`

Comment: @dzimiks adding larger padding will only increase the padding at end of  the sentence. In the codepen, notice the word "company" it doesn't have a left-padding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is here: http://jsfiddle.net/cLh0onv3/451/

Just add `box-decoration-break: clone;` and a box-shadow to display a pseudo-padding at ends of each line: `box-shadow: 0.250em 0 0 $black,-0.250em 0 0 $black;`